# Adding a list of values to jpa specification

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm developing advanced spring data jpa using specifications. I need help adding a list of values to the specification.

I know how to create a specification consisting of one value, like this:

```
public static Specification<Contract> isOfStatus(ContractStatus status) {
    return (Specification<Contract>) 
           (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(
                    root.get(Contract_.STATUS), status);
}
```

I need help making the same Specification but with `List<ContractStatus> statusList` so that not only one status could be filtered. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` with a list of status like this

```
public static Specification<Contract> isOfStatus(List<ContractStatus> status) {
     return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> 
                              root.get(Contract_.STATUS).in(status);
}
```